# jquery check radio button

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

PHP keeps saying `unidentified index: gender`?  I'm not sure where the error is.

HTML:

```
<label>Gender:</label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="0">Female
```

JQuery:

```
gender: $("input[@name=gender]:checked").val()
```

PHP:

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
if($gender == '') {
  echo 'Please select gender';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[@name=gender]:checked")
```

That is an invalid selector in modern jQuery.  This means that no element is found, and therefore no value is set for `gender`.  You need to remove the `@` and add quote marks:

```
$("input[name='gender']:checked")
```

[See the API for the attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: it still wont work `gender: $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val()`

Comment: @boyee007 How about showing some more code, then? The bit around that line would be particularly useful. Is other information being successfully passed?

Answer (score 0):

sorted. thanks

```
gender: $('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val()
```